# The constructor should be payable if you send value

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm running this code on remix IDE. Everything is working fine except the `function transfertocontracts(uint amount) public`. I'm trying to transfer some ethers for e.g. 10 to my contract and then later using this function `function Transfer_Contract_Amount() public` I will transfer all the amount of contract to specific address.

The problem is that when I run `function transfertocontracts(uint amount) public` I'm getting this Error:

> Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. debug the transaction to get more information.

```
contract SLA {
    
    address seller;
    
    
    event DepositFunds(address from, uint amount);
    
    constructor() payable public {
        seller = msg.sender;
    }
    

    function transfertocontracts(uint amount) public {
       address(this).transfer(amount);
    }
    
    function seePerson_Amount() public view returns(uint) {
       return seller.balance;
    }

    function seeContract_Amount() public view returns(uint) {
       return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    function Transfer_Contract_Amount() public {
       seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send ether only by using the value attribute which you can set while interacting with the Smart Contract. Below is the working code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
contract SLA{

 address payable seller;


event DepositFunds(address from, uint amount);

constructor() payable public {
    seller = msg.sender;
}


function transfertocontracts(uint amount) payable public{

}

function seePerson_Amount() public view returns(uint){
   return seller.balance;
}

function seeContract_Amount() public view returns(uint){
   return address(this).balance;
}

function Transfer_Contract_Amount() payable public{
    seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
}
```

To check you can run it on [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and on the run tab on the left side you can putt the value of ether to send and run the transfertocontracts function further to store the value its a good idea to use the msg.value.

Comment: great can you please mark it correct and upvote so other can know it too. Thanks:)

Comment: one more question.. How I will tackle this thing when I will use this smart contract with web3.js.. will this thing will be done using metamask?

Comment: in web3 you have to send the value parameter with the amount of ether which goes through the metamask to approve the transaction and then it will be sent to SmartContract